# img request with large URL

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to trigger img request using javascript

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'a very large URL comes here';
```

When this request is triggered with a large size URL, sometimes I see error as "out of memory" in firebug console.

I want to know does 'the URL size limit of ~2k chars' applies to image requested using javascript also ???

Has anyone ever encountered such issue, 'out of memory' because of large img url?

thanks,
lucky

Comment: Nope, the limit doesn't apply (at least not if the `src` is a normal image). How large is the image? What browser and OS are you in?

Comment: It is only a 1px image, Mac 10.8.4, Browser Firefox, I see error in firebug console. I see this issue intermittently.

Comment: A server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a URI is longer than the server can handle

Comment: Ahh, so the URL *itself* is large? Yeah, that counts towards the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE has a 2k limit on all urls regardless of how they are called. I have never seen an out of memory in firebug

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the limits on the URL length applies however you make a request.

It's however very unlikely that the size of an URL would cause a memory problem. It's more likely that the image that is loaded is too large, or even corrupted so that the decoding process uses too much memory.

For an URL that is too large for the server you would get an error message like `NetworkError: 414 Request-URI Too Large`.

Comment: ok thanks all for your replies, looks like I need to find a pattern to reproduce issue. And check if there is some other problem causing out of memory error.